# CONFIGURATION PHP.INI :: x86_64::on fedora 27:: [ERROR]

Tags: php

good evening, I'm new to fedora. And I have problems configuring the php.ini file more specifically in the date.timezone directive.

1. create a php blank file with the phpinfo function. 
   [image: phpinfo()]

[image: phpinfo() no set]

2. check the configuration of the /etc/php.ini file
   [image: php.ini]

3.check some other location of the php.ini file
[image: locate]

4.configure the date.timezone directive in the 2 files as well as /etc/php.ini
Development and production

5.opened the .ini files one by one (/etc/php.d)and only enabled extensions, and none changed the value of the date.tiemezone directive

6.create the script

```
<?php 
         date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota'); 
         $script_tz = date_default_timezone_get(); 
         if (strcmp($script_tz, ini_get('date.timezone'))){ 
             echo 'La zona horaria del script difiere de la zona horaria de la configuracion ini.'; 
          } else { 
         echo 'La zona horaria del script y la zona horaria de la configuración ini coinciden.'; 
} 
?>
```

7.confirm the server's time zone
[image: tiemzone]

8. execute the code local and url
   [image: local]
   [image: url]

9.nothing. Finally take the desperate measure of configuring in each of the files (/etc/php.d from step 4.) the directive date.timezone and nothing

[image: nothing]

Please help me, I go around and around and I do not see the solution. Thanks so much for any help

PD. In all the steps the services were restarted

```
systemctl restart mariadb
systemctl restart httpd
systemctl restart snmpd
```

Comment: Check if you are editing **correct** ini file. It's shown in `phpinfo()` output as well

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 2):

PHP is now run as a separate process, php-fpm.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart php-fpm.service
```

I would also create a `/etc/php.d/99-local.ini` file with your settings.